# Is there a way to prepend the namespace to the constructor in JSDoc? - e.g. new foo.Bar()

Tags: javascript, constructor, namespaces, jsdoc

I've been building out a project using rigorous JSDoc comments for the dual-benefit of intellisense  and getting some documentation built out. The project uses pre-ES5 and pre-module logic for how everything is set up:

- All of our classes are stored under a namespace, we'll call it `ct` for the sake of the question.
- **If we declare a `Checkbox` class under the `ct` namespace, it would be initialized with a call of `new ct.Checkbox(opts)`**

I've figured out how to handle all the quirks related to my project structure except for one: JSDoc outputs the constructor in documentation as `new Checkbox`, which does not match the implementation. So my question is:

**How can I include the namespace prefix in the outputted constructor?** Can I accomplish this somehow with a tag I include on the constructor function? Would I need to make a custom JSDoc template that does this for me? Would I need to combo the markup plugin and `@hideconstructor` tags to ham-fistedly replicate this?

The format of the Checkbox class looks something like this:

```
/**
 * @memberof ct
 * @class
 * @classdesc A checkbox input entity
 * @extends ct.Base
 *
 * @param opts {ct.Checkbox#Options}
 */
ct.Checkbox = function(opts) { ct.Init(this, arguments); };
ct.Checkbox.prototype = ct.Inherit(ct.Base, /** @lends ct.Checkbox.prototype */ {
    /** @type string */ _id: null,
    /** @type boolean */ _value: null,

    ...

});
```

This leads to this (snipped) picture of the JSDoc output:
[image: JSDoc output snippet]

As you can see (hopefully... I've been having weird cert issues with imgur lately), the `ct` prefix is entirely missing from the constructor, as well as the class' name. I would like to prefix the name with the namespace as well, but that's relatively minor compared to the constructor.